# Blender cycles render is rendering in 2 minutes even tho its a basic scene

Tags: rendering

I need to headless render and it renders 25 samples in 2 minutes but I need that to be below 5 seconds any optimizations I can do?

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Please [edit] your post to provide more information.  We don't have any idea what your scene is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have first searched for the (many) postings on Cycles rendering performance.  There are so many properties to adjust that it can be disorienting.

You can set a time limit on Cycles render, but that can too often vary the quality on each frame that might be a problem.

In Rendering panel, try reducing the "Sampling >> Render >> Max Samples" down from the default (128?) to a lower but acceptable value (try 32), and possibly turn enable "Sampling >> Render >> Denoise".

"Sampling >> Render >> Noise Threshold" of > 0 can help to adjust the acceptable render time.  Try "0.001" or "0.01"

Also adjust "Light Paths" (downward).

Vary these a bit up or down so that you minimize render time while still obtaining acceptable images that are not too grainy.

Comment: I tried that but i decided to just change samples and resolution it now works thanks

Comment: @Robluxable the number of knobs and dials in blender is daunting!